# Designated initializer should only invoke a designated initializer on 'super' xcode 6.3.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Using xcode 6.3.1 and building the project for IOS 8.3 device .Getting  Designated initializer should only invoke a designated initializer on 'super' error , could someone please adjust the code please.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (!nibNameOrNil) {
        return [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    }
    NSLog (@"%@ is now deprecated, we are moving away from nibs.", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    return [self initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error talks for itself here. Do not invoke one of the init methods on 'self' from one of the init methods. You are invoking:

```
[self initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

And you should rather invoke:

```
[super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Or if you have some additional logic in 'self' for this init you should redesign your common initialise logic call stack.

Bottom line: do not invoke [self init...] from init, only [super init...] Or add additional, your custom (not overridden) init method.

Moreover: You are invoking for init twice.